# Error 400 when using Add-AzureVhd

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, vhd

I try to upload a vhd to azure (fixed size of 30GB), but it always gives me an error after the end of upload.

Before that, I have imported my publish settings file, I set as default my subscritption and I set the default storage to vhds

`Add-AzureVhd -Destination "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/vm.vhd" -LocalFilePath "C:\Users\****\Desktop\vm.vhd"
MD5 hash is being calculated for the file  C:\Users\****\Desktop\vm.vhd.
MD5 hash calculation is completed.
Elapsed time for the operation: 00:02:59
Creating new page blob of size 32212255232...
Add-AzureVhd : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureVhd -Destination "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/vhds ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureVhd], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceM
   anagement.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand`

Do you have any idea on how to troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas to troubleshoot. I have just tried your same challenge without problems.

**First**, I think your error pops up before the upload. Because the whole process looks like this. And it seems that your error pops up right after the try to create a new blob. After that comes a lengthy process where the empty spaces of the VHD are detected.

```
PS C:\Users\pkirch> Add-AzureVhd -LocalFilePath 'C:\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\test30gb.vhd' -Destination "https://webdavsvr.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/test30gb.vhd"
MD5 hash is being calculated for the file  C:\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\test30gb.vhd.
MD5 hash calculation is completed.
Elapsed time for the operation: 00:02:58
Creating new page blob of size 32212255232...
Detecting the empty data blocks in the local file.
Detecting the empty data blocks completed.
Elapsed time for upload: 00:00:00

LocalFilePath                              DestinationUri                                           
-------------                              --------------                                           
C:\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\test30gb.vhd https://webdavsvr.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/test30gb.vhd
```

Some while ago I posted a [script to upload a VHD on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/pkirch/7e6049c61e18672ee52b). Have a look if you're not missing a step. Those are mainly:

1. Setting the current subscription.
2. (if you have already a storage
   account and a container you don't have to create a new one)
3. Setting the current storage account for the current subscription.

```
    # Settings

    $SubscriptionName = "Azure MSDN - pkirchner"
    $StorageAccountName = "pkteststorageaccount"
    $Container = "vhds"
    $LocalVhd = "C:\Users\pkirch\fixedvhd20mb.vhd"

    # Select my Microsoft Azure Subscription.
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

    # Create new storage account.
    New-AzureStorageAccount -Location "West Europe" -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -Type Standard_LRS

    # Create container for VHDs.
    $StorageAccountKey = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName

    New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey.Primary -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName | `
    New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $Container -Permission Off

    # Add-AzureVhd needs the CurrentStorageAccountName to be set.
    Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccountName $StorageAccountName

    # Build destination path automatically.
    $NewContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $Container
    $VhdFile = Split-Path -Path $LocalVhd -Leaf
    $Destination = $NewContainer.CloudBlobContainer.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "/" +  $VhdFile

    # Upload VHD
    Add-AzureVhd -Destination $Destination -LocalFilePath $LocalVhd
```

**Second**, if you're not missing any steps, I would try to look for errors using Fiddler. Using Fiddler with PowerShell for Azure is not straightforward. Here is [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2013/01/30/using-fiddler-to-decipher-windows-azure-powershell-or-rest-api-https-traffic.aspx) how to do it.

Comment: It works! I have no clue why it didn't work before... But thanks a lot!